# Converting Time Zone Issue

Tags: sql, database, date, timezone, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to get all records created on 1-Apr-2013. As the time and date in DB are stored in UTC, and user input would be in local time, I apply timezone conversion on user input, to convert the date(local) into UTC so that it would fetch the correct record.

```
AND SORDT.NAME = 'New Install'
AND SORD.X_ORDER_SUB_TYPE = 'New Registration'
AND SORD.CREATED >= (FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('1-Apr-2013 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
AND SORD.CREATED < (FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('2-Apr-2013 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
ORDER BY SORD.CREATED ASC
```

But the query result was wrong. If I ran the query above I would get first record created was on "01-APR-2013 09:25:39"(there are other records created prior to this record), and the last record(ORDER BY SORD.CREATED DESC) created was on "02-APR-2013 00:56:04"(both result are already converted into local time).

And the I ran below query, which using the UTC time as input(1-Apr-2013 00:00:00 = 31-MAR-2013 16:00:00 utc), I'll get the correct records fetched.

```
AND SORDT.NAME = 'New Install'
AND SORD.X_ORDER_SUB_TYPE = 'New Registration'
--AND SORD.CREATED >= (FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('1-Apr-2013 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
--AND SORD.CREATED < (FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('2-Apr-2013 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
AND SORD.CREATED >= TO_DATE('31-MAR-2013 16:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND SORD.CREATED < TO_DATE('01-APR-2013 16:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
ORDER BY SORD.CREATED ASC
```

The query returned, first record created was on "01-APR-2013 00:00:36", and last record at "01-APR-2013 23:08:39", which are the correct.

What could be the issue here? Both are kind of the same thing. Below is the first part of the code that accept user input argument, and then convert the value to UTC, which I ran to check the value, and its totally the same(output: 31-MAR-2013 16:00:00).

```
SELECT
(FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('1-Apr-2013 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "DATE"
FROM
DUAL
```

I hope I made my question clear and I appreciate any advise and input to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: What database software and version are you running?